# jQuery scroll animate div across screen and back

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to recreate something I have seen on another website Ben the Bodyguard and I'm just wondering how it is done, I understand it's some kind of loop but I'm unsure of how to go about it.

Basically, it's the part where the train goes across the screen..

http://benthebodyguard.com/index.php

If you look at what I have done, it just goes to a certain point and then back, how can I get it so it goes along the screen and then back again..?

http://jsfiddle.net/VWqyw/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pGvgc/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();    
    $("#block").css({ "left": windowWidth}); 

    $(window).scroll(function(){       
        $("#block").css({ "left":  windowWidth  - $(window).scrollTop()});
    });
});​
```

Basically just using the vertical scroll position to adjust the horizontal position of the block.

By the way, if your planning on doing a lot of animations on the page, it might be worth thinking about using a javascript library like [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/), something like that can allow you to do some great things relatively easily...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 480 && $(window).scrollTop() < 900){
             $("#block").css({ "left": $(window).scrollTop() - 480 });
        };      
    });
});​
```

This positions the element relative to the scroll position of the page within a given range